# How to assign a Term Sets to a Page layout on saving with out using taxonomy field control in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I have created a custom page layout with a taxonomy field control in it. I can assign the term sets and terms to this page layout with this taxonomy field control.

Now what i require is, can we able to assign these term sets to a page layout with out using taxonomy field control.Instead they have to assign on clicking a save button of a page in Edit mode.

I have done this by follwing the article in below link.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alimaz/archive/2009/12/08/content-organizer-and-managed-metadata-service.aspx?

Please somebody help me to solve this .

---

Answer (score 0):

Add Enterprise Keywords to the parent content type and then use XSLT to modify the display.

Comment: So, an XSLT crash course is beyond the scope of this comment.

Comment: But if you want to learn it, buy Marc Anderson's XSL book for $25

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the Mavention Meta Fields feature from Waldek Mastykarz.  It's easy to use and works great.  [Easy Meta Data Editor](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/easy-editing-meta-tags-publishing-pages-mavention-meta-fields/)